# PGFPlots Parametric Plot, Arrow Spacing by Constant Time

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows

For a parametric plot of a particle's position (x(t),y(t)), is it possible to use`pgfplots` to draw arrows equally spaced in time to indicate the direction of travel?

For example, with (x(t),y(t)) = (t,t^2), I know how to produce arrows equally spaced in length:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,smooth,xlabel = $x$, ylabel =$y$, minor tick num =1, grid=both, unit vector ratio*=1 1,enlargelimits = true]
\addplot[thick, variable=\t, domain=0:2, decoration={
    markings,
    mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.99 step 2em with {\arrow [scale=1.5]{stealth}}
    }, postaction=decorate] ({t^2}, {t^4});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

yielding

[image]

But can I get constant spacing in time, similar to:

[image]

Comment: Pgfplots has its quiver plot handler which is supposed to draw arrows. For a parametric plot, you could easily show the derivative. The arrows would be placed at the sample positions, so they would depend on t.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I'm not exactly sure what you're envisioning. Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make use of the `quiver` plot handler which is shipped with `pgfplots`. The `quiver` plot handler draws arrows at every input sample.

To this end, it requires the input coordinates as usual *and* arrow coordinates for every input coordinate (i.e. x,y, u, v).

In your case, we could easily sample all required values. Since you have `unit vector ratio*=1 1` in your listing, we can normalize all arrows to length 0.1 as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=14cm,
axis lines = middle,smooth,xlabel = $x$, ylabel =$y$, minor tick num =1, grid=both, unit vector ratio*=1 1,enlargelimits = true]
\addplot[smooth, thick, -stealth,variable=\t, domain=0:2]
    ({t^2}, {t^4});

\def\NORM{sqrt((2*t)^2 + (4*t^3)^2)}
\addplot[thick, red,-stealth,samples=12,variable=\t, domain=0.1:2,quiver={
        u=2*t/\NORM, v=4*t^3/\NORM,
        scale arrows=0.1,
    }]
    ({t^2}, {t^4});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\NORM` is the vector norm of the vector `(u,v)`; together with `scale arrows=0.1`, we get the desired effect. Here, we need *two* `\addplot` statements: one which draws the plot as such and one which draws merely the arrows.

For comparison, here is the same figure with `scale arrows=1`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is working great! I did not know about `quiver`.