# Why are all of the nodes in this standalone tikz document moved to the bottom left? I am using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes, standalone

I have the following code that I am using in `pgfplots` in a standalone `tikz` document:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                     tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
                 }}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=both,
                 xmin=-1.5, xmax=9.997,
                 ymin=-1.9975, ymax=5.9975,
                 axis lines=middle,
                 xlabel=\(x\), ylabel=\(y\),
                 xticklabels={}, yticklabels={},
                 clip=false,
                 y axis line style={Stealth-Stealth},
                 x axis line style={Stealth-Stealth}
            ]

        % graph curve
        \addplot[stealth-stealth, domain=-2.15:4.15, samples=50] ({x^2-2*x}, {x+1});

        % points on curve
        \node [circle, fill=black, scale=0.4, label=below left:{\(t=0\)}] at (0, 1) {};
        \node [circle, fill=black, scale=0.4, label=below left:{\(t=-2\)}] at (8, -1) {};
        \node [circle, fill=black, scale=0.4, label=above left:{\(t=2\)}] at (0, 3) {};
        \node [circle, fill=black, scale=0.4, label=above left:{\(t=4\)}] at (8, 5) {};

        % orientation of curve, code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142650/296881
        \def\NORM{sqrt((2*t-2)^2 + 1^2)}
        \addplot[thick,-latex, , samples=6, domain=-1.5:3.5, variable=\t,quiver={
            u=(2*t-2)/\NORM, v=1/\NORM,
                scale arrows=0.1,
        }]
        ({t^2-2*t}, {t+1});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the entire document. I expected it to look like this:
[image]
When I run the code within the `tikzpicture` environment with `\documentclass{article}`, that is what I get, the correct result. However, when I run the above code with `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`, I get that all of the nodes are clumped together at the bottom left like this:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` (you should get a warning that suggests doing this actually)? The reason is that only in newer versions, the coordinates inside an `axis` environment are also valid for `\draw` or other "normal" Ti*k*Z commands, but for older versions they are not and you would need to type `(axis cs:1,1)` instead for just `(1,1)`.

Comment: BTW, the MWE also messes up for `\documentclass{article}`.  Your article code must be slightly different.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I had `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` in the `\documentclass{article}` but not the `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PGFPlots, you are advised to always set the `compat` option, because this will affect the way how certain parts of the syntax are interpreted. For older versions of PGFPlots, you would have to type `(axis cs:1,1)` instead of `(1,1)` if you want to place some coordinate of a Ti*k*Z path at the relevant position inside the `axis` environment. For newer versions, this is not needed anymore, but to actually make use of the new syntax, you need to set the `compat` option to a newer version. Check the [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) for more information about this.

Hence, you either need to change the coordinates for the Ti*k*Z commands in your code to meed the requirements of the older syntax (with `axis cs`), or you need to set the value for the `compat` option to a relatively new version (or just use `newest`). I would recommend setting the `compat` option.

So, a working solution would look like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest, % or at least 1.11
    every axis/.append style={
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
         xmin=-1.5, xmax=9.997,
         ymin=-1.9975, ymax=5.9975,
         axis lines=middle,
         xlabel=\(x\), ylabel=\(y\),
         xticklabels={}, yticklabels={},
         clip=false,
         y axis line style={Stealth-Stealth},
         x axis line style={Stealth-Stealth}
    ]

        % graph curve
        \addplot[stealth-stealth, domain=-2.15:4.15, samples=50] ({x^2-2*x}, {x+1});

        % points on curve
        \node[circle, fill=black, scale=0.4, label=below left:{\(t=0\)}] at (0, 1) {};
        \node[circle, fill=black, scale=0.4, label=below left:{\(t=-2\)}] at (8, -1) {};
        \node[circle, fill=black, scale=0.4, label=above left:{\(t=2\)}] at (0, 3) {};
        \node[circle, fill=black, scale=0.4, label=above left:{\(t=4\)}] at (8, 5) {};

        % orientation of curve, code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142650/296881
        \def\NORM{sqrt((2*t-2)^2 + 1^2)}
        \addplot[thick,-latex, samples=6, domain=-1.5:3.5, variable=\t, quiver={
            u=(2*t-2)/\NORM, v=1/\NORM,
            scale arrows=0.1,
        }]
        ({t^2-2*t}, {t+1});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]